# Jmeter better way to go through list of array instead each value only call for missing values from JSON response

Tags: regex, arraylist, jmeter, beanshell

Hi I have Test Plan where I am creating a CSV File to write the list of employees with the Names.
First HTTP Sampler returns a list of multiple employee IDs which I use in my next Sampler Request as an array list like
employee\12354,78687,78687,98798,97987,978698 the second sampler returns a JSON Response like

```
[{
    "id": 456345,
    "FirsrName": "John",
    "LastName": "Wood"
    },
    {
    "id": 567456,
    "FirsrName": "Marry",
    "LastName": "Wood"
    },
    {
    "id": 675867,
    "FirsrName": "Alice",
    "LastName": "Chang"}]
```

Now I am writing all those nodes to the CSV file with id, firstname and lastname this is all fine. But the second sampler sometimes returns a less number of records than what was request let say I sent 5 ids but it only return 3. I want to get a list of all the missing ids in the second Request.

The way I am doing at the moment is using 
while controller -> Beanshell Sampler with all the regex logic and setting the value to Fail if doesn't exists in the Response from Second Sampler then using the if controller and HTTP Sampler inside it it works fine I am getting what I need but the issue/ concern I have is inside the While Controller Beanshell Sampler has to run for all the IDs from the Arraylist from the first Request this seems like not a good design or approach.

I want to avoid running Beanshell Sampler for all the IDs somehow.

[image]

Image attached
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, forget about Beanshell, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting).

Assuming you have [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) of [Integers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) from the first request you can get the values which are not present in the second response as follows:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns lesser amount of IDs
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def myIds = vars.getObject('myIds')
   log.info('IDs from first request: ' + myIds)
   def responseIds = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$..id').collect()
   log.info('IDs from second request: ' + responseIds)
   def commonIds = myIds.intersect(responseIds)
   def differentIds = myIds.plus(responseIds)
   differentIds.removeAll(commonIds)
   log.info("IDs which were not present in response: " + differentIds)
   ```
3. That's it, you will see the values which are present in the original ArrayList and not present in the second response in the *jmeter.log* file:

   [image]

References:

- [Collection.intersect()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#intersect(java.util.Collection))
- [Collection.plus()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.3/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#plus(java.util.Collection))
- [Jayway JsonPath](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri. Now after getting the missing IDs how do I pass an individual ID to next Request for all miss9ng IDs? I can use vars.put("differentids", differentIds) and then somehow get the count and use the while controller and out the RQ  under or is there a simpler way?

Comment: I would go for ForEach Controller like it's described in [Using Regular Expressions in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter/) article, just make sure the variables look like `var_1=78687`, `var_2=978698`, etc.

Comment: I am using like this 
    def arrayOutPut =  vars.getObject('id_ALL').split()
def commonIds = arrayOutPut.intersect(responseIds) I am getting an error on this
    javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: [Ljava.lang.String;.intersect() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.ArrayList) values: [[

In my extractor I am matching with -1 and have compute concatenation ticked -- need little bit more help